# Errors while trying to compile wxWidgets project

Tags: compiler-errors, codeblocks, wxwidgets

When trying to compile an wxWidgets example in Code::Blocks, I get following errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in wx3 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxmsw31d_core|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxbase31d|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxpngd|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxzlibd|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|
```

I have set compiler to search in these directories:

- `%pathtolibrary%\wxWidgets-3.1.5`
  and
- `%pathtolibrary%\wxWidgets-3.1.5\lib\gcc_dll\msw`

Also when I delete the second path, I get error that `setup.h` can not be found.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: @theyechnician274, you should add the linker search path. Or create wxWidgets-based project in C::B and everything will be setup for you..

Comment: @Igor I have added search path to the linker and created Code::Blocks wxWidgets project, yet still I am getting error that setup.h is missing.

Comment: [Here's a good guide](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47231) for using wxWidgets with Code::Blocks on windows.  If you follow the guide, the paths will be configured correctly so that all the necessary includes and libraries can be found.